# isolated storage - windowsphone

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage

How can i (Create,Read,Write,Delete) Files and Directories in Isolated Storage on Windows Phone?(VB.Net)(Visual Studio 2012)

---

i use this codes 
but i see some error.

Create file:

```
Dim sw As New StreamWriter(New IsolatedStorageFileStream("FirstRun\a.txt", FileMode.Create, file))
sw.WriteLine(Textbox1.text)
```

read form isolated storage:

```
Dim file As IsolatedStorageFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()
file.CreateDirectory("UserTexts")
Dim sw As New StreamReader(New IsolatedStorageFileStream("UserTexts\user.txt", FileMode.Open, file))
```

read file:

```
TXTBlock.Text = sw.ReadToEnd()
sw.Close()
```

Delete file:

```
Dim file As IsolatedStorageFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()
file.DeleteFile("Temp\a.farsmob")
```

Delete folder:

```
file.DeleteDirectory("Temp")
```

Create folder:

```
Dim file As IsolatedStorageFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()
file.CreateDirectory("FirstRun")
```

Comment: I see some error What error you are getting..?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this link for isolated storage. This is best for isolated storage beginners..

[Isolated Storage](http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/all-about-wp7-isolated-storage--intro-to-isolated-storage)